# Facing issue with paint method for QPushButton when used QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qt5

I have implemented `PushButtonDelegate` for a column in `QTableView` since we are using `QSortFilterProxyModel` to filter the table view.
I am setting this delegate to one of the columns as shown below...

```
table_->setItemDelegateForColumn(11, new PushButtonDelegate(table_));
```

The `PushButtonDelegate` is derived from `QStyledItemDelegate` and I have overridden `createEditor, setEditorData, setModelData, updateEditorGeometry, and paint` methods as shown below...

```
PushButtonDelegate::PushButtonDelegate(QObject* parent) :QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
    if (const auto table_view = qobject_cast<QTableView*>(parent))
    {
        my_widget_ = table_view;
        btn_ = new QPushButton(button_text_, my_widget_);
        btn_->hide();
        //my_widget_->setMouseTracking(true);
        connect(my_widget_, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(CellEntered(QModelIndex)));
        is_one_cell_in_edit_mode_ = false;
    }
}
QWidget* PushButtonDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() == constants::kUse)
    {
        const auto btn = new QPushButton(parent);
        const auto value = index.data().toString();
        btn->setCheckable(true);
        btn->setChecked(value == "Yes" ? true : false);
        btn->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
        connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(UpdateUseButton(bool)));

        return btn;
    }
    else
    {
        return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
    }
}

void PushButtonDelegate::UpdateUseButton(bool checked) const
{
    if (const auto selection_button = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(sender()))
    {
        const QString value = selection_button->text();
        selection_button->setText(value == "Yes" ? "No" : "Yes");
        selection_button->setChecked(value == "Yes" ? false : true);
        selection_button->setCheckable(true);
    }
}

void PushButtonDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() == constants::kUse)
    {
        const auto value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();
        const auto pb = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(editor);
        pb->setChecked(value == "Yes" ? true : false);
        pb->setText(value);
        pb->setCheckable(true);
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor, index);
    }
}

void PushButtonDelegate::setModelData(QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() == constants::kUse)
    {
        const auto pb = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(editor);
        const auto value = pb->text();
        pb->setChecked(value == "Yes" ? true : false);
        pb->setCheckable(true);
        const auto ptr = dynamic_cast<QSortFilterProxyModel*>(model);
        ptr->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor, model, index);
    }
}

void PushButtonDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() == constants::kUse)
    {
        painter->save();
        btn_->setGeometry(option.rect);
        const auto value = index.data().toString();
        btn_->setCheckable(true);
        btn_->setText(value);
        btn_->setChecked(value == "Yes" ? true : false);

        if (value == "Yes")
            painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());
        else
            painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.shadow());

        const QPixmap map = btn_->grab();
        painter->drawPixmap(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), map);

        painter->restore();
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}

void PushButtonDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget* editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

I am facing the following issues...

1. I have to click on the button 3 times to change the text from "No" to "Yes".
2. The highlighting of the buttons is not proper as shown (Button should be highlighted when the text is `yes`)...

[image]

Need help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for having to click a cell 3 times to change the value is because you need a double click to edit (which creates the editor) and another click to call `UpdateUseButton`. You don't need to do it this way, you can instead perform the click when you create your editor. In fact, you don't even need the `UpdateUseButton` as you can make the necessary changes in `setModelData`. Add the following slot to your `PushButtonDelegate`:

```
void commitAndCloseEditor();
```

and then implement the class like this:

```
QWidget* PushButtonDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() == constants::kUse)
    {
        const auto btn = new QPushButton(parent);
        const auto value = index.data().toString();
        btn->setCheckable(true);
        btn->setChecked(value == "Yes" ? true : false);
        btn->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
        
        // You don't need this, you can update your data in setModelData instead
        // connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(UpdateUseButton(bool)));
        
        // the click will commit the data and close the editor
        // we connect it with a queued connection so that the slot is called after this function exits
        connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &PushButtonDelegate::commitAndCloseEditor, Qt::QueuedConnection);
        emit btn->clicked(false); // perform a click programatically to that the commitAndCloseEditor will be called after we exit this function 
        return btn;
    }
    else
    {
        return QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor(parent, option, index);
    }
}

void PushButtonDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() == constants::kUse)
    {
        //nothing to do when you are in your delegate column
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor, index);
    }
}

void PushButtonDelegate::setModelData(QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() == constants::kUse)
    {
        // set your model data here
        model->setData(index, (index.data().toString() == "Yes") ? "No" : "Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::setModelData(editor, model, index);
    }
}

void PushButtonDelegate::commitAndCloseEditor()
{
    auto* editor = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(sender());
    emit commitData(editor);
    emit closeEditor(editor);
}
```

Notice that I've used a `Qt::QueuedConnnection` for connecting the `clicked` signal. This ensures that the `commitAndCloseEditor` slot will be called after both `createEditor` and `setEditorData` have exited (easy to check by using print statements in the beginning of each function). If you remove the queued connection, then the `commitAndCloseEditor` will be called before `createEditor` returns the actual editor, hence the slot will do nothing as the editor is not open yet.

Now, for the `paint` method... it would seem that `btn_->setChecked` is the reason for not properly showing the background color in the buttons. I'm not sure why it behaves like that, but a workaround would be to use stylesheets like so:

```
void PushButtonDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if (index.model()->headerData(index.column(), Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() == constants::kUse)
    {
        painter->save();
        btn_->setGeometry(option.rect);
        const auto value = index.data().toString();
        
        btn_->setText(value);
        
        QString stylesheet = QString("background-color: %1").arg((value == "Yes") ? "green" : "red"  );
        btn_->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);

        const QPixmap map = btn_->grab();
        painter->drawPixmap(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), map);

        painter->restore();
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

Toggling the value should now work with a double click and the result (on my Windows box) looks like this:

[image: outcome]